# Light Timer behind a dimmer?

Tags: lighting

Does anyone know of a light timer that will work behind a dimmer?

It is for a reptile cage, my basking light has to be on a dimming thermostat, and I need that thermostat to turn off for 30 mins 3 times a day. The thermostat doesn't have this function, and the thermostat serves other devices that need to be used during this time, so I cannot turn off the entire thermostat.

So is there any light timer, that I can use behind a dimmer, that will accept and be okay with being dimmed?

Comment: There are well made industrial quality timers that some people use on their electric water heaters. But I see the problem with using a timer *behind* the dimmer--the timer needs near to full voltage to function. One solution would be for the timer to be connected before the  dimmer, you'd get another thermostat and have it dedicated to the reptile cage.  Another solution would be to get a timer which operates on an independent power source with an input and and output separate from its power source. Surely these are available, but may be costly.

Comment: Or use the timer to control a relay which then switches the dimmed light.

Comment: How many watts is the heater? Will you be leaving the dimmer in the same setting at all times, or what  are the conditions which would lead you to changing the dimming setting? I sense an XY problem here...

Comment: I sense it a product @Harper doesn’t know exists: https://www.google.com/search?rlz=1CDGOYI_enUS590US590&hl=en-US&ei=oVVkW42OHaq_jwSTvraYCA&q=dimming+thermostat+for+reptiles

Comment: @Tyson actually I had a hunch. A couple million reptile owners are a big enough market for a custom product.

Answer (score 1):

I would use a simple intermatic timer being powered by another source then use the contact set in the timer to break the power to the heater. This would be a code compliant way to control the heat cycle. I do not know of any timer that could work as you describe but they may be out there. As far as intermatic they make clockwork style that you put lugs on a dial up to fancy digital units that you program. There are other brands I use intermatic because they last at least the clockwork ones almost never fail.

Comment: Another good timer for this application, also made by Intermatic, is the ST01, which has (3 year replaceable lithium button) battery powered electronics.    A hobbyist could buy a suitable extension cord and cut it in half, using both halves to wire the timer.  OP will need a few more things, junction box, cover, strain reliefs, etc... I’d specify all the parts to buy in an alternate answer, but the answer would get downvotes and comments that the parts aren’t listed for those uses.

Comment: I have used that model a nice unit. I agree the cord idea would work and be cheap, if it is enclosed in a project box you could use a inlet and outlet mounted in the box and use wire scraps to wire from the timer to the inlet and outlet and it would be totally legal.+